# airline seat using for

Tags: java, arrays, loops, javascriptserializer

I want my result to appear like this, each three in a line

```
********Flight SA220*******

000

000

000

000

000
```

but it ends up like this

```
**** Flight SA220 ****

000000000000000
```

any suggetions on what to do ??

here is my java code

```
System.out.println("**** Flight "+flightCode[0]+" ****");   
  for(int j=0 ; j<seat[0].length ; j++)
    for (int k=0; k< seat[0][j].length;k++)         
        if (seat[0][j].length%3 == 0)
         System.out.println(seat[0][j][k]);
        else
         System.out.print(seat[0][j][k]);
```

Comment: Print a new line sometimes?

Comment: this code needs some whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `if` you need to change your `seat[0][j].length` to `k`. The length of the array never changes, you need to check if the index (where the loop is in the array) is `%3`

```
System.out.println("**** Flight "+flightCode[0]+" ****");
for(int j=0 ; j<seat[0].length ; j++){
    for(int k=0; k< seat[0][j].length;k++){     
        if(k%3 == 0){
            System.out.println(seat[0][j][k]);
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(seat[0][j][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println()` adds a newline at the end. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29

Comment: Now it's inconsistent. This would use `println(s)` in one place and `print(s+"\n")` in another.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would also put a newline after each character printed, which isn't what was meant.

Answer (score 0):

Just add either `System.out.print("\n");` or `System.out.println();` in the outer loop after the inner loop.

You can get rid of the if statement:

```
System.out.println("**** Flight "+flightCode[0]+" ****");   
for(int j=0 ; j<seat[0][0].length ; j++)
{
    for (int k=0; k< seat[0].length;k++)
        System.out.print(seat[0][k][j]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: this has gave me each 5 in a line not each 3

Comment: @SarahAlofi Ah, you didn't mention that your array was sideways. Try it now.

Comment: @SarahAlofi If it worked, would you mind upvoting and accepting it?

Comment: I'm trying to vote up but it gives me voting up needs 15 reputations !